# Take specific data from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I take data to ViewBag in this way:

```
ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(DB.Cities, "CityID", "CityName");
```

that in this manner all rows are retrieved. I added `CountryID` to the table in the database . How to retrieve only the rows with a specific `CountryID` ?

Comment: You would normally do that in the controller.

Comment: This is a piece of code from the controller.

Comment: Right, I think the SelectList threw me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please not that I'm assuming a lot here, since I don't really have all the code I need. Basically, if your `DB` object is the database context and the `Cities` object is your table, you can just specify the condition for the elements that should be selected.

```
ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(
       DB.Cities.Where(x => x.CountryID == desiredId).ToList(),
       "CityID", 
       "CityName");
```